# fallo de lógica en do while

Tags: javascript

Tengo un fallo y no puedo comprender el por qué, tengo una función que se encarga de guardar en un array a los alumnos que cumplen determinada condición (aquí no hay inconveniente) pero necesito que el bucle se repita hasta cubrir la cantidad de alumnos y es donde tengo un error ya que solo entra una vez. Sé que un `for` es lo que debería utilizar pero quiero saber si puedo hacerlo de esta manera... Alguien puede explicarme el por qué? Gracias

```
function asignaBeca(){
    let num_becas = 3;         //Becas disponibles
    let becados = [];
    var matriculados = 3;     //Veces que debe repetir
    do {
        var alumno = {
            nombre: window.prompt("Nombre: "),
            edad: window.prompt("edad: "),
            titulo: window.prompt("Titulo: "),
        };
        if (alumno.edad > 17 && alumno.titulo == "si") {
            becados.push(alumno);
            num_becas--;
        }
        matriculados--;
    } while (matriculados == 0);
}
```

Comment: Debes tener cuidado con los valores que le asignas a num_becas y matriculados pues si el valor de matriculados es mayor al de num_becas, num_becas puede tener un valor negativo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `do-while` se va a ejecutar una sola vez y después, si la condición dentro del `while` se cumple (es verdadera), entonces se ejecuta nuevamente, y se repite este proceso.

El problema es que la condición está mal, `matriculados === 0` nunca es verdadero en tu código, lo que tal vez quisiste decir fue `matriculados !== 0`, sin embargo siempre es mejor idea utilizar la comparación mayor que o igual, para no tener problemas con los puntos flotantes.

```
function asignaBeca(){
    let num_becas = 3;         //Becas disponibles
    let becados = [];
    var matriculados = 3;     //Veces que debe repetir
    do {
        var alumno = {
            nombre: window.prompt("Nombre: "),
            edad: window.prompt("edad: "),
            titulo: window.prompt("Titulo: "),
        };
        if (alumno.edad > 17 && alumno.titulo == "si") {
            becados.push(alumno);
            num_becas--;
        }
        matriculados--;
    } while (matriculados > 0);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación

Answer (score 1):

*Hacer mientras*, esa es la consigna de **[do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/do...while)**, por lo que la condición debe ser **mayor** a 0

```
function asignaBeca() {
   let num_becas = 3;         //Becas disponibles
   let becados = [];
   var matriculados = 3;     //Veces que debe repetir
                
   do {              
      var alumno = {
         nombre: window.prompt("Nombre: "),
         edad: window.prompt("edad: "),
         titulo: window.prompt("Titulo: "),
      };

      if (alumno.edad > 17 && alumno.titulo == "si") {         
         becados.push(alumno);
         num_becas--;
      }
                            
      matriculados--;                    
   } while (matriculados > 0);
}
```